# Force Macbook Pro on AC mode using broken battery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, power

I have a Macbook Pro 13" Retina (Early 2015) running 10.12.6 with a broken battery (Replace now alert) but I still couldn't find a proper battery in my region.

In this case I should shut down the device to move and it seems loosing power also resets the date and time and also breaks hibernate mode which I can use.

I'd like to know is there any solution for forcing AC Mode so it ignores battery (Performance issue due to changing between battery and ac somehow in runtime).

I also tried SMC and NVRAM reset but no chance either.

Please let me know if there should be more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the performance issue is because of the battery issue. When battery is not recognized by the OS `X86PlatformPlugin` (Can be seen in disas, but need confirmation) uses `CPUFloor` of your device model plist in `/S/L/E/IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/X86PlatformPlugin.kext/Contents/Resources/`.

The issue was battery does not recognized on boot and for MBP 2015 13" `CPUFloor==800` which is too low.

BTW thanks to `PikerAlpha` you can use [`freqVectorEdit.sh`](https://github.com/Piker-Alpha/freqVectorsEdit.sh) to change your PowerManager plist. I also changed `CPUFloor` to higher number so MBP can be used smoothly again.